# Unable to serve a text file with no extension from Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, text-files, mime-types

I'm trying to serve a text file that has no extension from within a Web App.

The file is located in the .well-known folder. Other files (with json extension) from the .well-known folder are accessible, but when I try to access the file with no extension, the app redirects to the home page.

I modified the web.config and added support for 2 mime types (shown below) with no positive results.

The content of the web.config as it is now is listed below:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Slp.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
<staticContent> 
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the frame work and version of your web app?Where does your file resides in deployed folder?root directory or in any sub folder?

Comment: Hi @Harshitha, the Web App is set to use .NET 6.0 (LTS), 64 bits. The file sits in the .well-known directory. Other files from the same directory can be served with no problem. The only difference is that those files have an extension (json for example) whereas the file I need to serve does not have an extension.

Comment: Can you please share the screen cap of directory with that file.

Comment: Thanks @Harshitha for looking into this. The solution I wrote resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 of the solution from this post [apple-app-site-association to return as application/JSON from a azure request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053398/apple-app-site-association-to-return-as-application-json-from-a-azure-request) solved the problem. I added a rewrite rule to serve a json file whenever the file with no extension was requested.

The web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Slp.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="apple_json_file" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="^.well-known/apple-app-site-association" />
             <action type="Rewrite" url=".well-known/apple-app-site-association.json" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I used apple-app-site-association.json instead of apple-app-site-association as file name, and I placed in the .well-known folder.